# SQLite calculating difference of date got incorrect result

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am having trouble calculating date difference in SQLite.
I've set the value type to timestamp when setting up the tables, but the calculation for date seems only apply to the first number of my date entry.
I've try to use to_date('01/01/2020', 'mm/dd/yyyy') but then it return error saying not support to_date. My code is below, any suggestion would be much appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE customer_join 
(
id INT,
country_code VARCHAR(10),
country_descrip VARCHAR(255),
register_date TIMESTAMP,
customer_id INT,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customer(id)
);

CREATE TABLE customer_order 
(
id INT,
item_name VARCHAR(25),
item_description VARCHAR(255),
number FLOAT(24),
order_date TIMESTAMP,
customer_id        INT,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES patient(id)
);

INSERT INTO customer_join
Values (1,  1,  'none', '1/22/2017',    100),
        (2, 1,  'none', '1/23/2017',    101),
        (3, 1,  'none', '1/24/2017',    102),
        (4, 1,  'none', '1/25/2017',    103),
        (5, 1,  'none', '1/26/2017',    104),
        (6, 2,  'none', '1/27/2017',    101),
        (7, 2,  'none', '1/28/2017',    106),
        (8, 1,  'none', '1/29/2017',    107);
INSERT INTO customer_order
Values (1, 'A', 'none', 1, '2/23/2020', 101),
        (2, 'B', 'none', 1, '3/11/2027', 100),
        (3, 'B, C, D', 'none', 1, '4/10/2023', 100),
        (4, 'B, C, E', 'none', 1, '4/11/2020', 100),
        (5, 'R', 'none',1, '4/12/2099', 102);
```

```
SELECT (order_date - register_date) TIME_TO_ORDER
    FROM customer_join cj
    INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT customer_id , MIN(order_date) order_date
            FROM customer_order 
            GROUP BY customer_id) co 
    ON cj.customer_id = co.customer_id;
```

The code gives me the result:

```
    TIME_TO_ORDER
    2
    1
    3
    1
```

Which is not I wanted. I was trying to figure out how long does it take for customers to place their first order. Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you want?  It is not clear.

Comment: Please also include your expect output, but a newcomer with MCVE deserve a upvote...

Comment: You should read https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: I have trimmed your post a little, including to remove a part which in my (and I believe at least @T.Peter ) opinion is not needed. Consider this a compliment.

Answer (score 0):

First, you must change the format of the dates in both tables to `YYYY-MM-DD`, which is the only valid text date format for SQLite.
Then use the function `julianday()` to get the difference in days between the dates:

```
SELECT cj.customer_id, 
       julianday(co.order_date) - julianday(cj.register_date) TIME_TO_ORDER
FROM customer_join cj 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT customer_id , MIN(order_date) order_date
  FROM customer_order 
  GROUP BY customer_id
) co ON cj.customer_id = co.customer_id;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=2ea77b04ccf9612e17874baf1818adb2).
Results:

```
customer_id | TIME_TO_ORDER
----------: | ------------:
        100 |          1175
        101 |          1126
        102 |         30028
```

Comment: Please explain how you work around the problem that e.g. `select julianday("10/11/2000");`yields no output. I do not get it. I do see that you do not use the MRE provided by OP.

Comment: @Yunnosch I mention in my answer that for SQLite only the format YYYY-MM-DD is valid. julianday() does not work with other formats.

Comment: But doesn't that mean "For a different database than you have, this is the solution ..."? Please at least discuss how the database can be changed to match. Ideally change the solution to work on OPs database.

Comment: @Yunnosch what do you mean by *For a different database than you have*? The database is SQLite. For SQLite there is a restriction: the dates must have the correct format. Is it difficult to understand?

Comment: OK, "For a different database structure, with different semantics/syntax of the columns, specifically the date columns, ....".